# Python pandas: adding different columns and rows from different lists

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following list of counters:

```
Counter({'Task': 9, 'Story': 4, 'Bug': 1})
Counter({'Task': 6, 'Story': 4, 'Technical Debt': 2, 'Bug': 1, 'Spike': 1})
Counter({'Task': 12, 'Story': 4, 'Bug': 1, 'Spike': 1})
Counter({'Task': 4, 'Technical Debt': 1, 'Story': 1})
Counter({'Task': 9, 'Story': 2, 'Technical Debt': 2, 'Spike': 1, 'Bug': 1})
Counter({'Task': 12, 'Spike': 1, 'Story': 1})
Counter({'Task': 6, 'Story': 2, 'Bug': 2, 'Improvement': 1, 'Spike': 1})
Counter({'Task': 16, 'Story': 3, 'Bug': 1})
```

I want to add those into my DataFrame to achieve the following:

```
   Task Story Bug Technical_Debt Spike Improvement
0.   14     4 N/A             N/A   N/A         N/A
1.    9     4   1             N/A   N/A         N/A
2.    6     4   1              2     1          N/A
3...
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this using list comprehension with `pd.concat` and dataframe constructor:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

clist = [
    Counter({"Task": 9, "Story": 4, "Bug": 1}),
    Counter({"Task": 6, "Story": 4, "Technical Debt": 2, "Bug": 1, "Spike": 1}),
    Counter({"Task": 12, "Story": 4, "Bug": 1, "Spike": 1}),
    Counter({"Task": 4, "Technical Debt": 1, "Story": 1}),
    Counter({"Task": 9, "Story": 2, "Technical Debt": 2, "Spike": 1, "Bug": 1}),
    Counter({"Task": 12, "Spike": 1, "Story": 1}),
    Counter({"Task": 6, "Story": 2, "Bug": 2, "Improvement": 1, "Spike": 1}),
    Counter({"Task": 16, "Story": 3, "Bug": 1}),
]

df = pd.concat(
    [pd.DataFrame(clist[i], index=[i]) for i in range(len(clist))]
)


df
```

Output:

```
   Task  Story  Bug  Technical Debt  Spike  Improvement
0   9.0    4.0  1.0             NaN    NaN          NaN
1   6.0    4.0  1.0             2.0    1.0          NaN
2  12.0    4.0  1.0             NaN    1.0          NaN
3   4.0    1.0  NaN             1.0    NaN          NaN
4   9.0    2.0  1.0             2.0    1.0          NaN
5  12.0    1.0  NaN             NaN    1.0          NaN
6   6.0    2.0  2.0             NaN    1.0          1.0
7  16.0    3.0  1.0             NaN    NaN          NaN
```

Comment: wow, thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @hcpeter You're welcome.  Happy coding.  Be safe and stay healthy.